# Salesforce iOS SDK pin protection for connected app is not working

Tags: connected-apps, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I have a connected app in developer org and have enabled the pin protection for that app. Using the new iOS SDK, I have created a ios application.
Even if the pin protection is checked, the passcode screen never appears.

I have visited few links on stack exchange for reference [PIN Security for a Force.com Mobile SDK App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46233/pin-security-for-a-force-com-mobile-sdk-app)

Also, I have rechecked the remote access consumer key in the bootconfig.plist file.

The pin protection is set with one-minute timeout and 4 digit pin.